# YAMLException: Error: duplicated mapping key at line 45, column 30: "beforeLineComment": false,

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm trying to use ESLINT with `eslint .`on my root dir and run into this error:

```
YAMLException: Cannot read config file: 
/mypath/node_modules/extend/.eslintrc Error: 
duplicated mapping key at line 45, column 30:  "beforeLineComment": false,
```

I have node v6.9.1
eslint is v3.12.1

This is my **`.eslintrc.json`** config file:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "indent": [2, 2],
        "quotes": [2, "single"],    
        "linebreak-style": [2, "unix"],
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "curly": 0,
        "no-use-before-define": [2, "nofunc"],
        "spaced-comment": [2, "always"],
        "space-before-function-paren": [2, { "anonymous": "always", "named": "never" }],
        "space-after-keywords": [2, "always"],
        "space-before-blocks": [2, "always"],
        "semi-spacing": [2, {"before": false, "after": true}],
        "no-var": 2,
        "object-shorthand": [2, "always"],
        "prefer-const": 2
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "mocha": true
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using json no YAML I have no idea why that error is ocurring.

Comment: That file doesn't even have 45 lines in it. Are you **sure** that's the file it's complaining about?

Comment: Unless `"root": true` is specified, eslint merges `.eslintrc` files [with files found in parent directories](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy). Perhaps that merging involves some YAML conversion and perhaps there is something strange in an `.eslintrc` file in a parent directory?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the exception that you posted, the error doesn't actually happens in your config, but in the config that you are extending from in `node_modules/extend/.eslintrc` (which already looks strange).

You can get a lot more information about config loading if you run eslint with `--debug` flag. It will print out all the information about config files that are being loaded and merged by ESLint. That should point you in the right direction for finding who is extending that config and why.